# Ratchet Ratchet\Http\HttpServer class doesn't exist

Tags: php, ratchet

I cannot find the Ratchet\Http\HttpServer class. Each time I run the following code it produces an error.

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Game\Load;
$server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Load())), 2000);
$server->run();
```

Class 'Ratchet\Http\HttpServer' not found

Comment: Did you already add the dependency with composer ? If you dont use composer you can try with a require for every class ...

Comment: The `vender/autoload.php` kind of implies he is using composer :P

Comment: Which version of Ratchet have you got installed?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, however I found my problem. For some reason the HTTP directory wasn't installed at all

Comment: @PlanetBOGO I have the same problem, tried many times but can't get it installed

Comment: Is there anyone who has solution of this problem ?